# What's the difference between assign and local in freemarker

Tags: freemarker

For instance:

```
<#assign foo="foo"/>
<#local bar="bar"/>
```

When should one be used instead of the other

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`#local` creates or replaces a variable that lives in the scope of the ongoing macro or function call, and thus is used inside a `#macro` or `#function`.

`#assign` creates or replaces a variable in the current namespace (or in the explicitly designated namespace via `in somenamespace`). If you don't use multiple namespaces (ie., you don't use `#import`) then you can think of them as global variables.

See also:

- Kinds of variables: http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_misc_var.html
- Namespaces: http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_misc_namespace.html